# Dynamic Control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on MVC Application
The Control name are stored in database like there is 5 rows that contains control name (ex. texbox,dropdown) and i retrieve that data from database on button click using pure MVC

So based on that data i want to create that controls in view

For Demo try it using creating one control in code than assigning it into ViewBag than using that ViewBag value in script but it is not working

Assign HTML tag to variable. =>
String _str = 'html tag of textbox appears here';

Assign Value into ViewData and trying to user it in View but not working. =>
ViewData["DynamicControls"] = _str;

Please suggest me the idea want to do it using MVC only.

Comment: You can already do that using helper methods in your Razor view. There are methods like EditorFor, etc which will display appropriate editors /input elements.

Comment: But the control which i want to create are comes from database on the basis of that data i want to create that control in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this.e.g
//in model
public class Controls{
        public string ControlName{get;set;}
    }

//in controller 

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Controls> _controls=new List<Controls>();//retrieve 
            data from db in your case

            var _c=new Controls();
            _controls.Add(new Controls(){ControlName="textbox"});
            _controls.Add(new Controls(){ControlName="radio"});
            return View(_controls); // 
        }
   //in view

    @model List<Controls>
        @foreach(var item in Model){
         <input type="@item.ControlName">
      }
```

Comment: code logic is perfect
but some how after creating input box through model in view it does not showing in my page

Comment: Working Perfectly fine but in pure mvc concept
while calling action Method from javascripit it is not working
with given code in javascript
 $.post("http://localhost:12345/Slot/CriteriaDetail/", { vLocationCode: vLocationCode, nCategoryId: nCategoryId })

Comment: yeah it won't work since ajax call expect the callback but our action is returning view.If you want to do this through the ajax call you can return PartivalView instead of view. Also if your requirement is only to retrive data why are you using $.post use $.get instead

Comment: How to Set Partial View in that Ajax call

Comment: Can You Please tell or give idea that how to retrieve all dynamically created controls value in Controller again while saving data